Is it definitely not allowed to access the object pointed to by the pointer with the keyword 'restrict' using other pointers?
2011 6.7.3.1 says:

1 Let D be a declaration of an ordinary identifier that provides a means of designating an object P as a restrict-qualified pointer to type T.
2 If D appears inside a block and does not have storage class extern, let B denote the block. If D appears in the list of parameter declarations of a function definition, let B denote the associated block. Otherwise, let B denote the block of main (or the block of whatever function is called at program startup in a freestanding environment).
3 In what follows, a pointer expression E is said to be based on object P if (at some sequence point in the execution of B prior to the evaluation of E) modifying P to point to a copy of the array object into which it formerly pointed would change the value of E. Note that “based” is defined only for expressions with pointer types.
4 During each execution of B, let L be any lvalue that has &L based on P. If L is used to access the value of the object X that it designates, and X is also modified (by any means), then the following requirements apply: T shall not be const-qualified. Every other lvalue used to access the value of X shall also have its address based on P. Every access that modifies X shall be considered also to modify P, for the purposes of this subclause…

Based on this sentence, I conceived a piece of code:
int main() 
{    
    int  A = 5;   
    int* restrict P;
    P = &A;           
    *P = 10;
    int *N = P； 
    *N = 20； 
}

I think that *P is an lvalue L, &*P is the address &L of L, and P is obviously based on &L. Now if we access the object X using L (*P), then as mentioned in the standard:
then the following requirements apply. Among them, there is one:

Every other lvalue used to access the value of X shall also have its address based on P.

Let’s continue to look at the code. Next, N is assigned the value of P. Then N should also be based on P. Because when P changes, N also needs to change. So this satisfies:

Every other lvalue used to access the value of X shall also have its address based on P.

Then I think that accessing object X via *N is not undefined behavior.
But what I learned before is that,
in each execution of the block where the restrict pointer P is declared, if an object that can be accessed (directly or indirectly) by P is modified by any means, then all accesses to that object in that block must be performed via P; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
Here I actually used *N (another ordinary pointer) to access the object X, so I am very confused now:

Is my program strictly in line with the standard (not undefined behavior)?
If my program is correct, does this mean that the object pointed to by the pointer modified by 'restrict' can be accessed using other ordinary pointers?
If my program is wrong, then how should we understand the words in the C 2011 standard?


I would be nice if you put some effort into the question. Indent your code correctly. Otherwise  it is not worth answering

@0___________:I might have some non-standard parts. I hope you can forgive me. I'm just starting to learn C language. This is my first question. I'm very happy to see your comment. I would be very grateful if you could explain it in more depth.


But what I learned before is that,… then all accesses to that object in that block must be performed via P;…

The definition of restrict in C 2011 6.7.3.1 does not say that. It does not contain the word “performed” at all. This text is not from the standard. You do not say where you learned this from. It is incorrect unless you take “via” to include indirect uses of the restricted pointer, as when P has been assigned to another pointer N.


Is my program strictly in line with the standard (not undefined behavior)?


*N=20; conforms to the requirement stated in the standard that “Every other lvalue used to access the value of X shall also have its address based on P.”


If my program is correct, does this mean that the object pointed to by the pointer modified by 'restrict' can be accessed using other ordinary pointers?


The object may be accessed by other pointers that are based on P. Accessing it through pointer (or any lvalue) not based on P would not conform to the rules in 6.7.3.1.

If my program is wrong, then how should we understand the words in the C 2011 standard?

The words in question are not those of the C standard; they are some other words you did not cite the source for.

This is my first question on this website after learning C language for half a year. I'm very happy to see your reply.     Forgive me for being not proficient in using this website.          " in each execution of the block where the restrict pointer P is declared, if '''  "       This sentence comes from the website https://zh.cppreference.com/w/%E9%A6%96%E9%A1%B5, and it is not a sentence in the C standard.
Thank you again for your reply.
